# css scroll bottom element

Tags: html, css

I want the mouse to be able to scroll the underlying content even if the mouse is inside the blue area.
is there any way to solve

```css
.account {
  width: 200px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: #0c82df;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 200px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.account-1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: #00bfad;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="account-1">
  <p>时间到了分开就是浪费</p>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>时间到了分开就是浪费</p>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>时间到了分开就是浪费</p>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>时间到了分开就是浪费</p>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <p>时间到了分开就是浪费</p>
</div>

<div class="account">

</div>
```

[image]

Comment: For me its not clear, but your blue div is positioned absolute relative to the body and the body does not scroll (you set overflow hidden) so if you remove overflow hidden to the body the body will scroll and the blue div remain absolute positioned at the top

Answer (score -1):

if you wanna *ignore element while scroll* use

`.account{pointer-events:none}`

this property disable any interaction with mouse cursor
[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

if you wanna scroll .account-1 when hover on .account you must put .account block inside .account-1 block, then .account-1 not lose focus

Comment: how this answer the OP question?

Comment: This css works, but the button inside my div is not clickable

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.